# XML tag <space> not accepted in a layout file (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, chipmunk

his is my first entry in StackOverFlow and my first steps with Android-Studio, with a hopefully not too severe problem.

The use of the tag  is offered, but after insertion it is marked red as an error.
The behaviour occurs regardless of the layout type.

[image: 1]

I am not clear why this is marked as an error.

I have tried to use other layouts.

My expectation:

The  tag is not marked as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover over the error, you'd notice a popup appearing. In this case, you are missing 2 compulsory attributes (width and height). adding them will remove the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Space` like any other view in a XML layout has some mandatory attributes you are not providing: `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`. Omitting these produces the red error underline.